# How to get list of participents joined the Twilio's whatsapp sandbox

Tags: twilio-api

anyone knows how to get the list of numbers joined the twilio's whatsapp sandbox. I am creating a automation script, in which, i want to send the whatsapp messages to all the Sandbox Participants.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any native method is available or not, but some how found a alernative solution. I fetched all the numbers who have joined the sandbox, using below code:

```
to = []
for msgs in client.messages.list():
    if("Join" in msgs.body):
        to.append(msgs.from_)
```